# Center site in the center of the screen

Tags: html, css, centering

I am developing a site and want to centralize this site in the center of the screen (horizontally and vertically) but can not.
I could only centers it horizontally.

Since I've been searching and the solutions I found when I try to apply them to my site, it all mangled.

This is the website http://amsdarquitetura.com.br/

Comment: You have some errors on your page, like multiple id:s with the same name. Try to fix them first: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<style type="text/css">

#global {
    position:absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px; /* half of the height */
    margin-left: -350px; /* half of the width */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: pink;
}

</style>
```

Put this on your parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal is easy:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrap {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      [content]
    </div>
</body>
```

Vertical is much more difficult, and will likely require CSS3 or javascript positioning.

Answer (score 0):

To lead you down the right path, try using JAVASCRIPT (might want to add a tag) to detect the window.height.

```
// The window.innerHeight and document.body.clientHeight will make sure it is cross-browser compatible.
function getHeight() {
    return window.innerHeight != null? window.innerHeight: document.body != null? document.body.clientHeight:null;
}
```

Then subtract the height of your main div.

```
var maindiv=500; //this is your total height of main div with content
var windowHeight = getHeight(); 
var displayHeight= windowHeight-maindiv;
```

Then divide by 2 (top/bottom)

```
var topMargin= displayHeight/2;
```

And finally, add a 'margin-top' to the main div.

```
document.getElementById('wrap').style.marginTop=topMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define a height and width for your whole site to keep it centered in both directions.

From there, it's just doing the math on your vertical centering. Horizontal is pretty automatic with defining a width and having the margin:0 auto; (Don't use 5px auto.).

Here's a decent article on vertical centering:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin to do this.  I see you already using jQuery on your main page.

http://www.seodenver.com/simple-vertical-align-plugin-for-jquery/

It seems the CSS options for doing this are complicated, unreliable, and hacky, as you found out.

You could implement a custom jQuery function to do the same thing.  But why maintain that code when someone else has the problem solved already?